# How are Dynamic Tests different from Parameterized Tests in JUnit 5?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

Almost all the examples of dynamic tests that I have seen, can be reworked and written using parameterized tests. So, which is a practical scenario where the Dynamic tests are the only option, or at least, better suitable than the parameterized tests.

The only "truly" dynamic test example in JUnit 5 docs is not practical.

Any ideas?

Comment: Good question. As it stands dynamic tests indeed don't have a clear application, particularly because they are not backed by an extension point (see [#371](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/371)).

Comment: Thanks for our comment @Nicolai. I read your inputs and I think I understand what your point is. However, my point here is not about the way to create the dynamic tests, only to understand the use case where the dynamic tests are particularly useful. I am not sure how extension backed dynamic test would answer this. I would like to know what problem the developers are trying to solve by introducing the Dynamic tests.

Comment: Regarding the latter: Dynamic tests were created long before parameterized tests. The reason to include them was to make sure tool maintainers are aware of the fact that tests might be created at run time. Oh, I now remember that one reason was to allow [lambda tests](https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-dynamic-tests/#Lambda-Tests).

Comment: The above link ,the author even admits that there doesn't seem to be a clear case for lambda tests vs. letting IDEs deal with boilerplate code generation, concluding that it was a fun experiement. Regarding JUnit 5's new dynamic test functionality, it seems more awkward compared to parameterisation libraries such as JUnitParams or even JUnit 5s own parameterisation functionality; As Nicolai mentioned, it seems to exist soleyl to let others know that tests can be created at runtime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike [`DynamicTest`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/DynamicTest.html), [`ParameterizedTest`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/ParameterizedTest.html) is not part of the core `junit-jupiter-api` but is in a separate artifact named `junit-jupiter-params` (see [3.12.1. Required Setup](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0-M4/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-setup)). This is because one of the core principles for JUnit 5 is to "prefer extension points over features" ([Core Principles · junit-team/junit5 Wiki](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/wiki/Core-Principles)).

The JUnit Jupiter API defines how to create and register dynamic tests as an extension point to JUnit while JUnit Jupiter Params defines a higher-level API for defining parameterized tests.

[JUnit 5.0 M5 Milestone](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/milestone/8)'s theme is currently "dynamic containers and minor API changes". With these expected changes test developers will be able to not only create dynamic tests but trees of dynamic tests (dynamic containers containing other dynamic containers and/or tests) which is something that cannot currently be done with paramterized tests. Such will prove, I think, very useful for creating specification-like tests.

In short, the idea as I understand it is to first release core extension points via "low-level" APIs (e.g. dynamic containers/tests) and then create and encourage 3rd parties to create extensions that leverage them (e.g. parameterized tests).

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on "Support for parameterized tests uses the dynamic tests API under the hood". What I understand is that the dynamic tests do not support lifecycle callbacks, but parameterized tests does. Probably I need to have a look at the source code?

Comment: @Yasin, I am not familiar with _all_ of the code for parameterized tests but I do know that each test case calls [`TestExecutionListener.dynamicTestRegistered`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener.html#dynamicTestRegistered-org.junit.platform.launcher.TestIdentifier-).

Comment: After thinking it through some more that statement doesn't appear to be completely true. Both APIs funnel into the same code but they appear to be more independent from one another than I initially thought.

Comment: One interesting thing: when running the same (thousands of sub-millisecond) `@MethodSource` tests and `DynamicTest`s, the dynamic test run was almost x10 faster to complete. This won't make much of a difference in most cases, but when your test is very fast, the overhead of @ParameterizedTest becomes significant.

Comment: [Dynamic tests](https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-dynamic-tests/) and [parameterized tests](https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-parameterized-tests/) are wholly independent - they do not share more code or concepts with one another than with, say, regular `@Test`s. Dynamic tests are not part of the lifecycle (e.g. no before/after) and there is no extension point for them. Parameterized tests are part of the lifecycle and are implemented via [an extension point](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0-M4/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestTemplateInvocationContextProvider.html).